# Handling taps on a map

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have an `iOS` app where I need to interfere with a map.
After searching a bit I came to the conclusion that I have to use an `MKMapView` object and probably implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.

I am now wondering how I can capture the touch point (meaning longitude and lattitude) when the user taps on the map. I suppose there is a much better way than fiddling around with a home made `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

To make it clear and simple, I have this kind of code to start with:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate,
    screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds,
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    .........

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        .........

        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 20.0),
            size: CGSize(width: screenSize.width,
                height: screenSize.height-70.0)))
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    .........
}
```

My question is: what do I have to do to handle the tap of the user on the mapView object?
Though I looked for the anwer before writing this post, I came with no clear solution.

Comment: There is only one way and it is using `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: You mean getting the point with TapGestureRecognizer and then converting to the map coordinates, using the origin and zooming factor of the map?

Comment: Yes I agree too `Nirav D`'s comment , when I try to handle the same scenario, I searched a lot, but finally I gone with `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Yes that was it  :)

Comment: Well, that sounds SAD :). But if that is the way it is. I'll have to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.getCoordinatePressOnMap(sender:)))
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Implementation of `getCoordinatePressOnMap` method.

```
@IBAction func getCoordinatePressOnMap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchLocation = sender.location(in: mapView)
    let locationCoordinate = mapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")
}
```

**Note :**

> convert(_:toCoordinateFrom:) :  Converts a point in the specified
>   view’s coordinate system to a map coordinate.

Hope it works for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate), there isn't any method that handles touches.

I think you have to detect touch using `UITapGestureRecognizer`. `touchesBegan` doesn't work because I think the map view intercepts that, just like a table view.

After you detected the touch location, use the [`convert(_:toCoordinateFrom:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452503-convert) method to convert the `CGPoint` in the map view's coordinate space to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` on the map.

If this all sounds too troublesome, you can use Google Maps instead. `GMSMapView` has a delegate method `mapView(_:didTapAt:)` method that you can implement.